# How to observe NSScroller changes?

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollView` subclass and I would like to update another `NSView` based on the current scroll position. I tried KVC-observing the `value` of `[self horizontalScroller]` but that never gets called.

```
// In awakeFromNib
[[self horizontalScroller] addObserver:self
                            forKeyPath:@"value"
                               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                               context:NULL];

// Later in the file
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                  ofObject:(id)object 
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                   context:(void *)context {
    if (object == [self horizontalScroller] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"value"]) {
        // This never gets called
    }
}
```

Do you see an error in my reasoning or know a better method of how to observe the scrolling of an `NSScrollview`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tell the scroll view's content view to post bounds changed notifications, then listen for NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification.

```
[[aScrollView contentView] setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(boundsDidChangeNotification:)
                                             name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:[scrollView contentView]];
```

As stated in the [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW1), you can get the current scroll position this way:

```
NSPoint currentScrollPosition = [[theScrollView contentView] bounds].origin;
```

Comment: I think it's funny how all answers about `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` always first tells people to set `setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications` , which is enabled by default on all views, unless you have manually disabled. It's even documented that way.