# Equivalent of UIScrollViewDelegate in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I am implementing a custom `NSScroller` class and I need to know when the scrollview is about to scroll and when it finished doing so. What would be an equivalent of `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `viewDidScroll`, etc for `NSScrollView`/`NSScroller`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to observe NSScroller changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693717/how-to-observe-nsscroller-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass [`NSScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and override `reflectScrolledClipView:`. Don't forget to call super's implementation!